# Is there a name for a rhyme scheme where the rhyming words have conflicting/twisted meaning?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, rhymes

I'm trying to analyse the Ballad of Serenity Valley which is the theme song for the tv series Firefly:

> take my love
>   take my land
>   take me where I cannot stand
>   I don't care
>   I'm still free
>   you can't take the sky from me

My interpretation relies on the meaning of 'take' in the second line, being different from the third line, which are a rhyming pair.

Is there a name for this scheme or pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **antanaclasis**
>
> a form of speech in which a key word is repeated and used in a different, and sometimes contrary, way for a play on words, as in *The craft of a politician is to appear before the public without craft*.
>
> http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/antanaclasis

There's a longer discussion of the device here:

http://literarydevices.net/antanaclasis/